# For first occurence of value in a column record minimum value from a different column

Tags: r

I have a data frame 'all', a subset of which looks like this

```
ONSETS_S    DURATIONS_S CUMUlATIVE_DURATION Phase Active  Block   TRIAL
0           2.926       2.926               1     NA      NA       NA
2.926       1.925       4.851               1     NA      NA       NA
4.851       4.851       9.702               1     Passive Baseline 1
9.702       1.54        11.242              1     Passive Baseline 1
11.242      4.851       16.093              1     Passive Baseline 1
107.183     1.925       109.109             1     NA      NA       NA
109.108     4.851       113.96              1     Active  Baseline 1
114.135     1.848       115.808             1     Active  Baseline 1
115.807     4.851       120.659             1     Active  Baseline 1
312.232     1.925       314.16              1     NA      NA       NA
314.157     4.851       319.011             1     Passive Baseline 1
319.008     2.387       321.398             1     Passive Baseline 1
321.395     4.851       326.249             1     Passive Baseline 1
415.797     1.925       417.725             1     NA      NA       NA
417.722     4.851       422.576             1     Active  GD       2
422.762     2.31        424.886             1     Active  GD       2
424.883     4.851       429.737             1     Active  GD       2
```

In the whole data frame there are total 6 phases, 5 types of entries in Block and up to 2 trials per block per phase. I want to create a matrix of minimum values in ONSETS_S for each Trial, when when Phase, Active and Block condition values are fixed.
For example, when `Phase == 1 & Active == "Passive" & Block == "Baseline"` the output should be `P_1_Passive_Onsets <- [4.851 314.157]`

Comment: You mention *"minimum values in ONSETS_S for each Trial"*, but `P_1_Passive_Onsets <- [4.851 314.157]` is not clear to me how that would work. Do you mean something like `ave(dat$ONSETS_S, dat$TRIAL, FUN = min)`?

Comment: I deleted the code you  had written because using for loops and ``assign`` is certainly not the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using `dplyr`.

It's not totally clear what you want, but from your description, it sounds like you want to group across levels of TRIAL, Phase, Active and Block and find the min/max values for each.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    group_by(TRIAL, Phase, Active, Block) %>% 
    summarise(min_val = min(ONSETS_S), max_val = max(ONSETS_S))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
# Groups:   TRIAL, Phase, Active [4]
  TRIAL Phase Active  Block    min_val max_val
  <int> <int> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     1 Active  Baseline  109.      116.
2     1     1 Passive Baseline    4.85    321.
3     2     1 Active  GD        418.      425.
4    NA     1 NA      NA          0       416.
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, list(min_val = min(ONSETS_S), max_val = max(ONSETS_S)), by=c("TRIAL", "Phase", "Active", "Block")]
   TRIAL Phase  Active    Block min_val max_val
1:    NA     1    <NA>     <NA>   0.000 415.797
2:     1     1 Passive Baseline   4.851 321.395
3:     1     1  Active Baseline 109.108 115.807
4:     2     1  Active       GD 417.722 424.883
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was already using `data.table` in my script so I used the second option and it worked.